# IntelliJ IDEA not loads all provided jars like Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

When I am importing project in IDEA through Maven POM file, IDEA does not import "provided" jars like what Eclipse does by default. Classpath used by IDEA always falls shorts with jars and I am unable to run project.

What is the way to get IDEA yo import the same jar files as Eclipse does by default?

Currently what I need to do is to first import the project from maven (POM file) to Eclipse and then import the Eclipse project into IDEA to achieve the right result.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the only really repeatable way to do this is to make the official, maintained build a stand-alone one (e.g. maven, gradle), and to have no dependency in your project (or your version control system) on any IDE whatsoever.

So, for instance, if you set up and maintain your build in maven, and use only external dependencies (no jars in your lib directory), then both eclipse and intellij (and netbeans, etc.) can load the pom.xml and build the code.

This also allows you to use a continuous integration server like Jenkins or Hudson.